# SQLDeveloper is slow at exporting results to CSV

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I run a 500k-Record query. It runs fast (15 sec) but it only shows the first 50 rows. When I right-click and export it, it takes around 2 hours and I see the counter advancing in chunks of 50 rows. It's definitely running the full query at that moment, but I was wondering if there was a faster method. Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK SQL Developer starts displaying the results once the first batch of it is received and not only after all was received. That's why you seem to quickly get a result but of course when exporting all rows in the result have to be fetched and that can take time.

Comment: Make sure you are exporting to a local drive (C: etc), not a network drive. Writing to a network drive can be several times slower.

Answer (score 4):

15 seconds isn't fast.

When you export the query results, we run the query, again.

Once the resultset is available, we'll start writing it to your file or editor straight away, and it'll happen about as fast as your network allows.

It'll get records in batches of 50 by default, that's configurable in the preferences on the Advanced page, but I wouldn't put that higher than say 500.

500,000 records isn't that big - not sure how wide/fat your records are, but this shouldn't take very long assume network latency isn't in play.

Instead of using the Grid - Export feature, you could also try this

```
spool c:\file.csv
SELECT /*csv*/ * FROM table;
spool off
```

Execute via F5

Comment: Just to add to Jeff's "15 seconds isn't fast", depending on the execution plan, then you might have spent 15 seconds to obtain *all* rows, and now you are fetching them, BUT it's also quite possible that you are going to spend 15seconds for *each* 50 rows you need to retrieve, at which point 2 hours is *not* a SQL Dev export issue but a query tuning issue